# Visual Studio Team Services - Build Alerts and Alert Filters Group Selected Clauses not Working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We are setting up **Build Alerts** to use with **Visual Studio Team Services 2015** however setting the **Alert Filters - Group Selected Clauses** is not clear from the interface - this is what I want to achieve.

`((definition1 || defintion2) && (status1 || status2 || status3 || statusTest1 || statusTest2))`

The only documentation [I could find](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/track/using-queries) which relates to this indicates that the current grouping should work however emails are not generated, if I remove the groupings emails are sent but the way the expression is evaluated is unclear.

[image]

**Update to comment**

I think the wrapping braces are included by default.

`(definitionName OR definitionName) AND (status OR testStatus)`

```
--
|   definitonName
|   OR definitionName
--
--
|   AND status
|   OR testStatus
--
```

Comment: don't you need the parent "And" clause to specify that both groupings should apply? (just speculating here, don't know for sure)

Comment: also, I would simplify your second grouping into `Status<>Succeeded OR TestStatus<>Succeeded`

Comment: @oldbam Ive update the query with your suggestions and the questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not to do with the *Group Selected Clause* but when using the **Field** - **DefinitionName** the `=` Operator did not work.
This was solved by using `Contains` instead.

[image]

`(definitionName OR definitionName) AND (status OR testStatus)`

```
--
|   definitonName
|   OR definitionName
--
--
|   AND status
|   OR testStatus
--
```